# Passing input to an executable using Python subprocess module

Tags: bash, python-2.7, subprocess

I have an input file called `0.in`. To get the output I do `./a.out < 0.in` in the Bash Shell.

Now, I have several such files (more than 500) and I want to automate this process using Python's subprocess module.

I tried doing this:

```
data=subprocess.Popen(['./a.out','< 0.in'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

Nothing was printed (data[0] was blank) when I ran this. What is the right method to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirection using `<` is a shell feature, not a python feature.

There are two choices:

1. Use `shell=True` and let the shell handle redirection:

   ```
   data = subprocess.Popen(['./a.out < 0.in'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()
   ```
2. Let python handle redirection:

   ```
   with open('0.in') as f:
       data = subprocess.Popen(['./a.out'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=f).communicate()
   ```

The second option is usually preferred because it avoids the vagaries of the shell.

If you want to capture stderr in `data`, then add `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` to the `Popen` command.  Otherwise, stderr will appear on the terminal or wherever python's error messages are being sent.

Comment: @Rayu Since the second method does not spawn a shell, I expect it to be faster and also use less memory.

Comment: don't use a list argument and `shell=True` together -- it is misleading (always pass a string instead). You could use `subprocess.check_output(['./a.out'], stdin=f)` here