# Python: Executing a shell command

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to do this:

```
paste file1 file2 file3 > result
```

I have the following in my python script:

```
from subprocess import call

// other code here.

// Here is how I call the shell command

call ["paste", "file1", "file2", "file3", ">", "result"])
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

`paste: >: No such file or directory.`

Any help with this will be great!

Comment: Redirection is never part of the command.

Comment: It is easy to emulate `paste` command in Python e.g.,: `for lines in izip(*files): print "\t".join(map(str.strip, lines))`

Answer (score 5):

You need to implement the redirection yourself, if you're wisely deciding not to use a shell.

The docs at https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html warn you not to use a pipe -- but, you don't need to:

```
import subprocess
with open('result', 'w') as out:
    subprocess.call(["paste", "file1", "file2", "file3"], stdout=out)
```

should be just fine.

Comment: I find that the shlex.split() function (in the standard libraries) is useful to make more readable code while using the subprocess module.  So I'd use call(shlex.split('paste this that'), stdout=out) ... for example.

Comment: @JimDennis actually, with no quoting &c needed, an even simpler `'paste this that'.split()` would be fine too:-).  But some people prefer to write lists out explicitly, and it's fine to do so if that's somebody's preferred style.

Comment: Yes, with that example.  As said the code can be considerably more readable and easier to maintain if the commands are rendered in the code as one would normally see them (quoted, etc) on a command line and then split as the shell would (shlex.split).  Manually splitting them into list literals in the source code is a bit error prone and, in my view, harder to read.

Comment: @JimDennis, I may have sweated more blood and tears fighting shell quoting and escaping than on most other broken-as-designed SW issues, so managing to carefully reproduce the same hell when I don't **have** to doesn't strike me as the best way to invest my time:-).

Comment: @JimDennis: `shlex.split()` may produce a wrong output e.g., `shlex.split(r'"\$x"')` -> `['\\$x']` but it should be `['$x']` instead -- pass a list to avoid subtle bugs instead of using `shlex.split()`.

Comment: All: clearly my suggestion is unpopular.  However, I still find it useful; I just won't do that in any of your projects.  As a guy who's primary focus has been operations rather than coding I find shell command line quoting to be second nature.  That's also the tendency among most to work with my code.  J.F. Sebastian: shlex.split() might produce wrong output for some subtle corner cases.  But your example is contrived.  If you paste a raw string like that in a list element you'd have exactly the same problem.  (Also $X must be evaluated by your code (os.environ['x']) unless shell=True).

Comment: @JimDennis: wrong. Both `call(r'echo "\$x"', shell=True)` and `call(['echo', '$x'])` produce the same output `$x`.

Answer (score 5):

There are two approaches to this.

1. Use `shell=True`:

   ```
   call("paste file1 file2 file3 >result", shell=True)
   ```

   Redirection, `>`, is a shell feature.  Consequently, you can only access it when using a shell: `shell=True`.
2. Keep `shell=False` and use python to perform the redirection:

   ```
   with open('results', 'w') as f:
       subprocess.call(["paste", "file1", "file2", "file3"], stdout=f)
   ```

The second is normally preferred as it avoids the vagaries of the shell.

#### Discussion

When the shell is not used, `>` is just another character on the command line.  Thus, consider the error message:

```
paste: >: No such file or directory.
```

This indicates that `paste` had received `>` as an argument and was trying to open a file by that name.  No such file exists.  Therefore the message.

As the shell command line, one can create a file by that name:

```
touch '>'
```

If such a file had existed, `paste`, when called by `subprocess` with `shell=False`, would have used that file for input.

Comment: This is usable as a quick hack but is not recommended for robust coding.  In particular someone naïvely following this example will be writing vulnerable (insecure) code.

Comment: @JimDennis Please review the more complete answer.

Comment: I think you should more strongly emphasize the caveat here.  Also I didn't see the rest of your answer when I posted my comment.  Did you you amend it?  Did my comments race your edits?

Comment: I had written a similar answer before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831277/passing-input-to-an-executable-using-python-subprocess-module and was adapting it to this case as you commented.

Comment: you could add [the link to "Security considerations", to warn about `shell=True`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind adding an additional dependency in your code base you might consider installing the [sh](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/) Python module (from [PyPI:sh](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh) using `pip`, of course).

This is a rather clever wrapper around Python's `subprocess` module's functionality.  Using `sh` your code would look something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from sh import paste
paste('file1', 'file2', 'file3', _out='result')
```

... although I think you'd want some exception handling around that so you could use something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from sh import paste
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as err:
    try:
        paste('file1', 'file2', 'file3', _out='result', _err=err)
    except (EnvironmentError, sh.ErrorReturnCode) as e:
        err.seek(0)
        print("Caught Error: %s" % err.read(), file=sys.stderr)
```

`sh` makes such things almost trivially easy although there are some tricks as you get more advanced.  You also have to note the difference between `_out=` and other keyword arguments of that form, vs. `sh`'s magic for most other keyword arguments.

All that `sh` magic make confuse anyone else who ever reads your code.  You might also find that using Python modules with `sh` code interlaced into it makes you complacent about portability issues.  Python code is generally fairly portable while Unix command line utilities can vary considerably from one OS to another and even from one Linux distribution or version to another.  Having lots of shell utilities interlaced with your Python code in such a transparent way may make that problem less visible.