# passing variables in cmd using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd, subprocess

I want to pass some variable in command prompt with some other text as well. I tried with this code and it doesn't work. Any hints what I might be doing wrong or what should I do instead?

There is a variable "v" which stores a URL and I want to pass this URL in the cmd with some other parameters.I have this code right now.

```
working_directory = os.getcwd()
p = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg -i 'v' -c copy getit.mkv'], cwd=working_directory)
p.wait()
```

But, it seems like this isn't working. I can't pass the variable "V". It just pastes V when I remove the quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the command as a list like below:

```
working_directory = os.getcwd()
p = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-i', v, '-c' 'copy' 'getit.mkv'], cwd=working_directory)
p.wait()
```

Or use `shlex.split()` which should handle this properly:

```
cmd = 'ffmpeg -i "{}" -c copy getit.mkv'.format(v)
p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), cwd=working_directory)
```

Comment: @user2408212: beware, [`shlex` may fail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468807/python-executing-a-shell-command/28468860#comment45287698_28468860). Use it only to get a *draft* list version of a command that you could fine tune later manually. btw, what is the point of using `cwd` with the current directory (`os.getcwd()`)?

Answer (score 2):

To pass a variable into a string you can use `format` method of `string`:

```
v = 'file.avi'
p = subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg -i {} -c copy getit.mkv".format(v)], cwd=working_directory)
```

Comment: You are using "file.avi" in the v cariable. But, like I said.. it contains a url.. and hence the script fails saying it cannot find the file specidifed..

Comment: @user2408212 that just an example, change the 'file.avi' to the file path you want to use. If that's url you need to download it first (or ask in your question how to download it via python)