# Escaping quotes in bash command using subprocess call and shlex

Tags: python, bash, escaping, subprocess, shlex

I am executing bash command using python's subprocess.call().
I am taking user input as an argument to my command like below.

```
my_command = 'command -option1 {0} -option2 {1}'.format(arg1, arg2)
```

Here arg1 and arg2 are user inputs but the problem is user input can have *quotes and spaces* so I want to surround arguments by double quotes like this.

```
my_command = 'command -option1 "{0}" -option2 "{1}"'.format(arg1, arg2)
```

Since I have no control over user input, input can contains double quotes or single quotes.  Hence I am replacing input with following escape sequence.

```
arg1 = arg1.replace('"', '\"').replace("'", "\'")
arg2 = arg2.replace('"', '\"').replace("'", "\'")
my_command = 'command -option1 "{0}" -option2 "{1}"'.format(arg1, arg2)
```

All looks good to me but when I execute command I get following error.

```
subprocess.call(shlex.split(my_command))
```

> File "/usr/lib/python2.6/shlex.py", line 279, in split
>       return list(lex)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.6/shlex.py", line 269, in next
>       token = self.get_token()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.6/shlex.py", line 96, in get_token
>       raw = self.read_token()   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/shlex.py", line 172, in read_token
>
> raise ValueError, "No closing quotation"
>
> ValueError: No closing quotation

**How can I deal with it ?**

Edit : I want to preserve those quotes and spaces in bash command.

Comment: Unrelated: `shlex` is not very sophisticated. [It may break easily: `r'echo "\$x"'`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468807/python-executing-a-shell-command#comment45287698_28468860). It is useful during development, to create an initial `args` list from an existing example command-line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't deal with quotation marks, spaces, etc.  Just use a list:

```
my_command = ["command", "-option1", arg1, "-option2", arg2]
subprocess.call(my_command)
```

Comment: This approach wont work because input can have spaces and split will be based on spaces.

Comment: My solution doesn't use `split`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not escaping quotes in your current code as `\"` is simply equal to `"`. You should use double escapes to escape the backslash (`\`) character:

```
arg1 = arg1.replace('"', '\\"').replace("'", "\\'")
arg2 = arg2.replace('"', '\\"').replace("'", "\\'")
```

Comment: Thanks Sekcuk
But problem is I want to preserve those quotes and spaces.

Comment: @AshokKumar That's why you should escape them using the method I suggested.